# How to read from java domain in spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to spring batch , have to implement a batch that reads from a java domain(basically a jar which have my database queries) by using pagination and write it to a well formed xml.I have gone through numerous examples but could not fine anything concrete on how a spring batch can read from java domain.

any help/suggestions would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to read for the jar? What is an "item" in your case?

Comment: I am trying to read database query results from the jar.Item will be result of the  query basically list of contracts.

Comment: for example I have an interface which gives me list<contracts> , so I want to call this method in the reader to get the list and pass it to processor but I have to read using pagination as the data is huge.

Comment: Sorry but it is still not clear to me. Please share an example and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have a jar which have some interfaces and sql to run .So one of it interfaces will give list<contracts> after querying databases.I have to call this interface method in the spring batch and get that list of contracts.  how to read list of items in item reader through a jar or service class and pass it on to processor .Will the processor takes the list and process it once or will it do one by one.

Comment: I tries using AbtractPagingItemReader but I want a list and that too from a service class.SO it was not of much help here.

Comment: This got resolved using query driven pattern in spring batch.